# Lowercase a list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, nested, lowercase

I have a list of lists:

```
data = [['SiteUrl','Url','Title'],['SiteUrl','Url','Title']]
```

How can I iterate through the list and lowercase all the content using python?

Comment: Is the depth of the nested list fixed? Or could there be a third level, too?

Comment: if you have un undefined depth of lists and/or mixed content write a recursive method which iterates all elements, if string call lower and if list call method on that list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
data = [[x.casefold() for x in sublst] for sublst in data]
```

Or functionally:

```
data = [list(map(str.casefold, x)) for x in data]
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold):

> Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it
>   is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over each of the inner lists:

```
data = [[string.lower() for string in sublist] for sublist in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `map()` all sub lists of `data` to `map()` that will make all of its elements `lower()`.

```
data= [['SiteUrl','Url','Title'],['SiteUrl','Url','Title']]

data = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y.lower(), x)), data))
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
[['siteurl', 'url', 'title'], ['siteurl', 'url', 'title']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary number of levels, you can try this recursion

```
data= [['SiteUrl','Url','Title'],['SiteUrl','Url','Title']]
def recursive_apply(x, f=lambda v: v.lower()):
    if type(x) is list: 
        return [recursive_apply(el) for el in x]
    return f(x)
recursive_apply(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

data = [map(str.lower, sublist) for sublist in data]

Answer (score 0):

The following will find a string or substring within a list or array and return the string.

```
foundStringList = [i for i in ListVar if stringORsubstring in i.casefold()] # returns string as list ["string"]

ListVar.index([i for i in ListVar if stringORsubstring in i.casefold()][0]) # returns index of first found string.
```

If you want to find all index containing string, you would make a for loop for foundStringList